# Not Understanding Template Error in My Code [ C++ ]

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14

I got an error in my Code :

```
"Nested name specifier 'Node<T>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization."
```

I'm not understand why this error happen.Guys how can i solve this error in my C++ code and the member function must implement outside of the class.

```
template<typename T, typename  =typename std::enable_if<isMyType<T>::value>::type>
class Node{
  T t;
public:
  T getT();
};

template<typename T, typename  =typename std::enable_if<isMyType<T>::value>::type>
T Node<T>::getT(){
return t;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear, there is no `Node` as class template taking one type parameter. You declared `Node` as class template taking two types.

Default type parameters should be only in declaration of template. In definition you don't provide it again.

Outside definition should be:

```
template<typename T,typename U>
T Node<T,U>::getT(){
    return t;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/wdJQko)